# ASP.NET Core MVC Route issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to setup an ASP.NET Core MVC site to support multilingual for multiple countries, for example:

- www.test.com/au/en (Australia, English)
- www.test.com/au/de (Australia, German)

To set the culture for the current user, I found this code

```
public static class GetRoutesMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseGetRoutesMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder app, Action<IRouteBuilder> configureRoutes)
    {
        if (app == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));
        }

        var routes = new RouteBuilder(app)
        {
            DefaultHandler = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<MvcRouteHandler>(),
        };
        configureRoutes(routes);
        routes.Routes.Insert(0, AttributeRouting.CreateAttributeMegaRoute(app.ApplicationServices));
        var router = routes.Build();

        return app.UseMiddleware<GetRoutesMiddleware>(router);
    }
}

public class GetRoutesMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;
    private readonly IRouter _router;

    public GetRoutesMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IRouter router)
    {
        this.next = next;
        _router = router;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var context = new RouteContext(httpContext);
        context.RouteData.Routers.Add(_router);

        await _router.RouteAsync(context);

        if (context.Handler != null)
        {
            httpContext.Features[typeof(IRoutingFeature)] = new RoutingFeature()
            {
                RouteData = context.RouteData,
            };
        }

        // proceed to next...
        await next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

I created a RequestCultureProvider that looks like this:

```
public class RequestCultureProvider : IRequestCultureProvider
{
    public Task<ProviderCultureResult> DetermineProviderCultureResult(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.GetRouteValue("language") == null)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult("en", "en"));
        }
        var langauge = httpContext.GetRouteValue("language").ToString().ToLower();
        return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(langauge, langauge));
    }
}
```

To setup routes I have this method:

```
private readonly Action<IRouteBuilder> GetRoutes =
    routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(name: "Default",
                        template: "{area}/{language}/{controller}/{action}",
                        defaults: new { area = "au", language = "en", controller = "home", action = "Index" },
                        constraints: new { area = new RequiredRouteConstraint(), language = new RegexRouteConstraint("^(en|de)$")  });
    };
```

Then in Startup.cs, in the Configure, I then have

```
// setup routes
app.UseGetRoutesMiddleware(GetRoutes);
// add localization
var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>() {
                new CultureInfo("en"),
                new CultureInfo("de"),
            };

var requestLocalizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(supportedCultures.First()),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures,
};
requestLocalizationOptions.RequestCultureProviders.Clear();
requestLocalizationOptions.RequestCultureProviders.Add(
    new RequestCultureProvider()
);
app.UseRequestLocalization(requestLocalizationOptions);
```

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but to layout my views in a more organised fashion, I setup a CultureViewExpander that looks like this:

```
public class CultureViewExpander : IViewLocationExpander
{
    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {
        return viewLocations.Select(s => s.Replace("%1", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName));
    }

    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
    {
        context.Values.Add("Language", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
    }
}
```

and it is implemented in the Startup.cs, in the ConfigureServices as

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
{
    o.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new CultureViewExpander());

    // {0} for the action
    // {1} for the controller
    // {2} for the area
    // %1 for language
    o.ViewLocationFormats.Clear();
    o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Views/Shared/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);

    o.AreaViewLocationFormats.Clear();
    o.AreaViewLocationFormats.Insert(0, "/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/%1/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
});
```

The supported languages work fine, but when I navigate to www.test.com/au/fr, I simply get a blank screen, but I need it to return a 404.  How can I get it to return a 404 for an invalid route value?

Comment: Could you show the part of code that mapping the `language` to the UI culture?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core correctly returns 404 error for not matched URL like `www.test.com/fr`. It's up to the browser how to deal with such response. Firefox just shows blank page as you described. IE, Chrome and Opera show page with error description, like:

[image]

You could customize ASP.NET Core behavior when error code should be returned. You could either use simple text messages by adding `UseStatusCodePages` to application configuration:

```
app.UseStatusCodePages("text/plain", "Status code page, status code: {0}");
```

You could also redirect user to custom error pages in case of request failure:

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/error/{0}");
```

Make sure path `/error/404` is correctly resolved, otherwise you get infinite redirection to this page.

Check this article for more details: [Error Handling in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling)